# Texture mapping on a circular 3D object

Tags: c++, 3d, texture-mapping

I'm trying to map a texture on a circular 3D object.

The texture that I chosed to apply is a simple map-saturation image. I'm using this algorithm in order to obtain the following result:

```
for (i = 0; i <= count / 2; i++)
{
    Vertex& v = vertex[j++];
    double rad = M_PI * 2.0 * ((double)i / (double)count);
    v = vDefault;
    v.x = (float)sin(rad);
    v.y = (float)cos(rad);
    v.u = v.y;
    v.v = v.x;
}
```

[image: texture mapped]

The problem is: I'd like to center the texture. I tried v.u = v.y * 0.5f + 0.5f but I'm getting weird results. How I can translate it?

Comment: https://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/spheremap.htm

Comment: A good way to debug problems with texture mapping is to use a debug texture. You could also use [this earth image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg), as it would be easier for other people to help you find the problem.